# Cannot get google-services.json file for Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I am currently working on updating the Google Login process in my app using google-services 3.0.0 and play-services 9.6.1 and am having troubles getting the required google-services.json file to include in my project.

I am following the setup guide and trying to get the json file from https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android.

When I pick my app from the dropdown menu I get a ['bad request' error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88lPM.png).

I went ahead through the process anyway, choosing only Google Login for the service but I still get an error when I attempt to download the google-services.json file

This is what is returned when I attempt to download the file

```
)]}'
{"code":3,"errorSpace":"generic","placeholders":{"trackingId":"123456789"},"status":400,"message":"backend error"}
```

Looking at the form that was sent in Fiddler, the query string is

```
["getArtifactRequest",null,"android:my.app.package","2","123456789"]
```

(After replacing the trackingId and the project Id numbers in these two requests)

Attempting to go back through the process gives me an error stating that the package already exists (Which it does). Other places seem to imply that I could use this method repeatedly as a way to re-generate the json file though.

The app was already listed in the OAuth 2.0 client IDs on the developer console site when I did this. I also went through it a second time for a debug version of the app which was not already created, but I received the same messages and outcome.

Has anyone else seen this issue and found out how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried logging out and clearing the cache of your browser and see if the issue still persists?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Looks like I get the same message after clearing cache / logging out. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching projects for a bit and checking back today, I went through the same process as listed and it worked just fine. I haven't changed any settings, so maybe it was a problem on their end for a while. Wish there was something more helpful to say about this, but it just works now.